# Does skipgram model uses backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, backpropagation

I just started to get interested in natural language processing and I was trying to understand the skipgram model from word2vec. I was reading [this interesting website](https://aegis4048.github.io/demystifying_neural_network_in_skip_gram_language_modeling#eq-18). However, in the mentioned source as well as many other places, they talk about backward propagation. But since we have explicit formulas for the gradient(see below, or section *[Training: Backward Propagation]* from the link), there is no (backward) automatic differentiation talking place right? So is this still backpropagation?

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W_{input}}= x\cdot (W_{output}^T\sum\limits_{c=1}^Ce_c)$$
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W_{output}}= h\cdot\sum\limits_{c=1}^Ce_c$$

Comment: Backpropagation can use either automatic differentiation or explicit gradient formulas.

Comment: @Sycorax Your comment leads me to suspect that different fields might use the term 'backpropagation' differently; I understood it to be synonymous with reverse-mode automatic differentiation. In other words, it's a dynamic program for _how_ to compute the gradients. The parameter updates are separate, and can be done with either explicit formulas or those computed by backpropagation. My answer to the user would be "If you directly implement the gradients, then there's no backpropagation."

Comment: @edamondo Can you please double-check your parentheses.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, I edited the typo. Yes, what you point out in your comment was exactly what confused me